# This webpage has a redirect loop Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've got multiple blogs installed on wordpress to create bilingual website. One of my blogs is installed in a root folder while another is the default blog that was installed originally. When I am opening my first blog, I get the following message: "This webpage has a redirect loop". My second blog installed in a root folder works fine. Clearing cache or cookies didn't help as this message appears in several browsers. I think the problem is with .htaccess file.

My .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the blogs and reinstalling WordPress with multi-site support. You can create separate blogs from within the WordPress interface there.